# What is the proper way to handle multiple asynchronous requests to the same server using JavaScript? Current and forecast weather data API requests

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

I have a page that shows weather. I have an account with **[Weatherbit.io](https://www.weatherbit.io/api)** to grab weather data from their API. The call to get current weather is this:

```
https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?key=<my_key>&lang=en&units=I&12345
```

The call to get forecast data is this:

```
https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?key="<my_key>"&lang=en&units=I&12345
```

I am currently making two separate asynchronous calls to the API, one for current and one for forecast.

Is this the way it is supposed to be done, or is there a better, or more accurately "proper", way to do this? Perhaps a way to get both current and forecast data with a single call?

The reason I am looking for this answer is because I seem to be getting these errors quite frequently:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at
'https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?key=<my_key>&lang=en&units=I&12345'
from origin 'http://127.0.0.1'
has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.
```

Comment: The error that you received is about cors, where the errors that show about multiple async request?

Comment: @MudziaHutama When it said _"header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed"_ I assumed it meant I made multiple requests to the API.